# Geohash not generated in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, geospatial, geohashing

I have created an index as follows:

```
POST /cabtrails
{
  "settings" :
{
  "number_of_shards" : 3,
  "number_of_replicas" : 1
 },
"mappings" : {
"cabtrail" :{
  "properties" : {
        "location": {
            "type":               "geo_point",
            "geohash_prefix":     true, 
            "geohash_precision":  "5m" 
          },
          "capture_time": {
                "type" : "long"

            },
          "client_id": {
            "type" : "long"

          }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

It works fine and an index is created.

I have entered one sample document as:

```
POST cabtrails/cabtrail
{
    "capture_time": 1431849367077,
    "client_id": 865527029812357,
    "location": "13.0009316,77.5947316"
}
```

This works fine as well.
Here, I am expecting that ElasticSearch will generate a geohash field/entry which I can use.

But, when I query, I get this:

```
GET cabtrails/_search
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 3,
      "successful": 3,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "cabtrails",
            "_type": "cabtrail",
            "_id": "AU2LrEaze2aqxPjHm-UI",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "capture_time": 1431849367077,
           "client_id": 865527029812357,
           "location": "13.0009316,77.5947316"
        }
     }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am expecting a geo-hash string like `u10hbp` somewhere in the query result, which I can use to query future location points. Or my concepts of geohash+ES are messed up?? Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/mapping-geo-point-type.html#_geohash_6) enabling *geohash* flag in geo_point indexes the *geohash* value .

There is a difference in what is indexed and what the *[_source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html)* field of the response represents.

The *_source* field in the response is the original raw json document that is passed for indexing to elasticsearch.

When you enable geohash flag the geo_point type is indexed using the geohash representation but the actual source  document is not altered

To get an idea of how geohash flag complements the way geo_point type gets indexed you could probably use the [fielddata_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fielddata-fields.html) api:

For the above example it would look something on these lines :

```
**Query**
POST cabtrails/_search
{

    "fielddata_fields" :["location","location.geohash"]
}
```

**Response:**

```
"hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "cabtrails",
            "_type": "cabtrail",
            "_id": "AU2NRn_OsXnJTKeurUsn",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "capture_time": 1431849367077,
               "client_id": 865527029812357,
               "location": "13.0009316,77.5947316"
            },
            "fields": {
               "location": [
                  {
                     "lat": 13.0009316,
                     "lon": 77.5947316
                  }
               ],
               "location.geohash": [
                  "t",
                  "td",
                  "tdr",
                  "tdr1",
                  "tdr1v",
                  "tdr1vw",
                  "tdr1vww",
                  "tdr1vwwz",
                  "tdr1vwwzb",
                  "tdr1vwwzbm"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```